# Find all solutions of the equation

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Find all solutions of the equation \begin{aligned}
x \cdot 2^{x-1}+1=y^2
\end{aligned} for all natural x , y.

Comment: If $y$ is even, the Right hand side is even, $\implies2^{x-1}$ must be odd $\implies x-1=0\implies y^2-1=1$ (no solution)

Comment: Yes, but if x=0, then y = 1 or y=-1, therefore just a solution, (0,1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on whether you count $0$ as a natural number, we may or may not include the solution $(x, y)=(0, 1)$.

Consider $x \geq 6$.

$x2^{x-1}$ is even so $y$ is odd.

Clearly $y>1$. Write $y=2z+1$, where $z$ is a positive integer. We get

$$x2^{x-1}+1=y^2=(2z+1)^2=4z^2+4z+1$$
$$x2^{x-3}=z^2+z=z(z+1)$$

If $z$ is odd, then we must have $2^{x-3} \mid z+1$. If $z$ is even, then $z+1$ is odd so we must have $2^{x-3} \mid z$. In any case, $2^{x-3} \leq z+1$, so

$$x2^{x-3}=z(z+1) \geq (2^{x-3}-1)2^{x-3}$$

$$x \geq 2^{x-3}-1$$

However since $x \geq 6$ we have $$2^{x-3}=8\cdot2^{x-6} \geq 8(1+(x-6))=7(x-6)+(x+2) \geq x+2>x+1$$

(Here we have used the inequality $2^x \geq 1+x$ for non-negative integer $x$)

We get a contradiction, so there are no solutions for $x \geq 6$.

It is fairly straightforward to check that $x=1, 2, 3, 4$ do not give solutions, while $x=5$ gives the solution $(x, y)=(5, 9)$.